# How to pass command line arguments to Deno?

Tags: command-line-arguments, deno, cmdline-args

I have a [Deno](https://deno.land/) app, that I wish to pass some command line args to. I searched the [manual](https://deno.land/manual), but found nothing.

I tried to use the same commands used in Node.js, assuming they might be sharing some for the std libraries, but it didn't work as well.

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2); 
// Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Node and Deno have hardly any APIs in common. This is intentional, Deno is meant to be a fresh start. The only APIs that Deno attempts to port directly are the standards-based browser APIs that you'd find in places like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Deno.args` to access the command line arguments in Deno.

To try it create a file test.ts :

```
console.log(Deno.args);
```

And run it with `deno run test.ts firstArgument secondArgument`

It will return you with an array of the passed args:

```
$ deno run test.ts firstArgument secondArgument
[ "firstArgument", "secondArgument" ]
```

Answer (score 23):

You can access arguments by using `Deno.args`, it will contain an array of the arguments passed to that script.

```js
// deno run args.js one two three

console.log(Deno.args); // ['one, 'two', 'three']
```

If you want to parse those arguments you can use [`std/flags`](https://deno.land/std/flags/#const-parsedargs--parseargs-options--), which will parse the arguments similar to [`minimist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist)

```js
import { parse } from "https://deno.land/std/flags/mod.ts";

console.log(parse(Deno.args))
```

If you call it with:

```
deno run args.js -h 1 -w on
```

You'll get

```
{ _: [], h: 1, w: "on" }
```

Comment: Why does the parser presume that `-h` needs a value after it, instead of just being a binary flag, like `ls -l`?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a stroll through the [standard library](https://deno.land/std/), you will find a library named [`flags`](https://deno.land/std/flags/), which sounds like it could be library for command line parsing. In the [README](https://deno.land/std/flags/README.md), you will find your answer in the very first line:

> ```js
> const { args } = Deno;
> ```

Also, if you look at [the Deno Manual](https://deno.land/manual/), specifically the [Examples section](https://deno.land/manual/examples/), you will find numerous examples of command line example programs that perform argument parsing, for example, [a clone of the Unix `cat` command](https://deno.land/manual/examples/unix_cat/) (which is also included in the [First Steps section of the Deno Manual](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/first_steps/)), where you will also find your answer in the first line:

> ```js
> for (let i = 0; i < Deno.args.length; i++)
> ```

So, in short: the command line arguments are a property of the global `Deno` object, which is documented [here](https://doc.deno.land/https/raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno/master/cli/js/lib.deno.ns.d.ts#Deno.args):

> ## `const Deno.args: string[]`
>
> Returns the script arguments to the program. If for example we run a program:
>
> ```js
> deno run --allow-read https://deno.land/std/examples/cat.ts /etc/passwd
> ```
>
> Then `Deno.args` will contain:
>
> ```js
> [ "/etc/passwd" ]
> ```

Note: According to the Manual, *all non-web APIs* are under the global `Deno` namespace.