# What is the Deno equivalent of process.argv in Node.js?

Tags: deno

When working with NodeJS, I can pass the arguments to a Node script like this:

> $ node node-server.js arg1 arg2=arg2-val arg3

And can get the arguments like so:

```
// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
//Output
0: node
1: /Users/umar/work/node/node-server.js
2: arg1 
3: arg2=arg2-val
4: arg3
```

**How to get the command-line arguments in Deno?**

Some experts suggested me to solve the problem by answers to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832639/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-deno)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass command line arguments to Deno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832639/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-deno)

Comment: There aren't multiple ways to get command line arguments just one, `Deno.args`

Comment: Maybe, rename the title to "What is the Deno equivalent of `process.argv` in Node.js?". At least that was the way I interpreted your question with my answer.

Comment: Great suggestion, Thanks! Done!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Deno [executable path](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.execPath) ~ `process.argv[0]`:

```
Deno.execPath()
```

#### File URL of executed script ~ `process.argv[1]`:

```
Deno.mainModule
```

##### You can use [`path.fromFileUrl`](https://deno.land/std@0.55.0/path/posix.ts#L437) for conversions of URL to path string:

```
import { fromFileUrl } from "https://deno.land/std@0.55.0/path/mod.ts";
const modPath = fromFileUrl(import.meta.url)
```

#### Command-line [arguments](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.args) ~ `process.argv.slice(2)`:

```
Deno.args
```

#### Example

```
deno run --allow-read test.ts -foo -bar=baz 42
```

##### Sample output (Windows):

```
Deno.execPath(): <scoop path>\apps\deno\current\deno.exe
import.meta.url: file:///C:/path/to/project/test.ts
  as path: C:\path\to\project\test.ts
Deno.args: [ "-foo", "-bar=baz", "42" ]
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can't use `import.meta.url` for this, it contains the current file (like `__filename` in Node), not the main file, unless they happen to be the same.

Comment: `Deno.mainModule` is now stable. See [comparison](https://deno.land/manual/examples/module_metadata) with `import.meta.url`.

Comment: @callum huh, this is exactly, what I have written? "// put this in your main file to get its full path"

Comment: ok but it's under a heading `File URL of executed script ~ process.argv[1]` and introduced as an alternative to `Deno.mainModule` in that context. Anyway as `Deno.mainModule` is long stable now, it can be edited

Answer (score 2):

To get your script’s CLI arguments in Deno, just use `Deno.args`:

```
> deno run ./code.ts foo bar
```

```
console.log(Deno.args); // ['foo', 'bar']
```

---

If you need something *identical* to Node's `process.argv` for compatibility reasons, use the official 'node' shim:

```
import process from 'https://deno.land/std@0.120.0/node/process.ts'

console.log(process.argv); // ['/path/to/deno', '/path/to/code.ts', 'foo', 'bar']
```

---

For illustrative purposes, if you wanted to manually construct a `process.argv`-style array (without using the official 'node' shim) you could do this:

```
import { fromFileUrl } from "https://deno.land/std@0.120.0/path/mod.ts";

const argv = [
   Deno.execPath(),
   fromFileUrl(Deno.mainModule),
   ...Deno.args,
]

console.log(argv); // ['/path/to/deno', '/path/to/code.ts', 'foo', 'bar']
```